# How to enable/disable some css attribute when changing between mobile/desktop mode?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a bootstrap3's RWD page , if I want the image floating right(or left) and make text wrapping around it , And when in mobile mode , disable the floating (or changing other attribute) value. How to achieve it ?

For example , this is what I want in wide screen :

```
<div style="float:LEFT; width: 300px ; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding:1px">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>image header</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  <div class="caption">This is image footer</div>
</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of ...</p>
```

It works OK. 
[image: desktop mode]

But in mobile device , I don't want the 'text wrapping image' effect. (because if the image is wide , the wrapping text is too narrow , hard to read) .

[image: mobile mode]

I have to disable the `float` and `width` style values in `xs` mode.

But I don't know how to correct implement this feature. This is what I can think of , very stupid :

```
<div style="float:LEFT; width: 300px ; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding:1px" 
     class="hidden-xs">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>image header</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  <div class="caption">This is image footer</div>
</div>

<div style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding:1px" class="visible-xs" >
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>image header</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  <div class="caption">This is image footer</div>
</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is ....</p>
```

It uses `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` to achieve this effect , very stupid.

Any with or W/O JS solutions are welcome , Thanks a lot !

====================================================

Updated

I partially solved the problem by introducing `block_float_left` and `block_float_right` class , as follows :

```
<div class="thumbnail block_float_left">
  <div class="caption"><h3>image header</h3></div>
  <a href="#" >
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
  </a>
  <div class="caption">This is image footer</div>
</div>
```

It maybe `block_float_left` or `block_float_right` hardcoded in the HTML . And in CSS , I defined :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {   
    .block_float_left {
        float:left;
    }

    .block_float_right {
        float:right;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {    
    .block_float_left {
        float:none;
    }

    .block_float_right {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

It works partially , because it cannot handle `width` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) so that you can change your code at different screen sizes. Assuming you simply want to remove the float then I would do something like this.

NB: I've only used an arbitrary size of 700px in my example you can change this as you need it.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img class="my-img" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eligendi dolorum aspernatur odio iusto natus autem deleniti dolores laboriosam consequuntur, sint veniam corporis quod voluptas eius consequatur tempora quidem culpa.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eligendi dolorum aspernatur odio iusto natus autem deleniti dolores laboriosam consequuntur, sint veniam corporis quod voluptas eius consequatur tempora quidem culpa.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-img {
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) { 
  .my-img {
    float:none; 
  }
}
```

JSfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ca5qv7uq/)

Comment: What if the `float` is left or right (dynamically generated by program) , I cannot hard code it in the css ... ?

Comment: You can still use the media query. In this case what the media query is saying is, there is no float on that element, until the screen size reaches `700px`. I'm not sure if this would cover your scenario

Comment: I mean , the server rendered this tag `<div style="float:LEFT; width: 300px ;...> ` , `left` or `right` is coded in the html , not in the css .

Comment: Actually, you might be able to do something like this: https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Hi , I've updated my question , adding a partially work solution . FYI.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra class and use media query.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/baykorhan/yjuL8d0y/1/
```